# Swift - label not updating in WatchKit from delegate callback

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, watchkit

I know the first question will be "are you running the code in the main thread" and the answer is yes, I am.

I have an Interface Controller present a modal, and I use a delegate callback to dismiss the modal and update a text label. Here's the code:

The delegate is declared

```
// SetFooInterfaceController.swift
protocol SetFooInterfaceControllerDelegate: class {
  func setFooInterfaceControllerDelegateDidTapSetFoo(foo: Int)
}
```

And the presenting VC passes itself as the context so the delegate can be set:

```
// SetFooInterfaceController.swift
weak var delegate: SetFooInterfaceControllerDelegate?

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
  super.awakeWithContext(context)

  if let presentingVC = context as? FooDetailInterfaceController {
    delegate = presentingVC
  }
}
```

When the button is tapped the delegate is called:

```
// SetFooInterfaceController.swift
@IBAction func setWeightButtonTapped() {
  delegate?.setFooInterfaceControllerDelegateDidTapSetFoo(foo)
}
```

And the delegate method is called in the presenting view controller:

```
// FooDetailInterfaceController.swift
func setFooInterfaceControllerDelegateDidTapSetFoo(foo: Int) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.fooLabel.setText(String(foo))
    self.dismissController()
  })
}
```

Now the modal is dismissed, setting breakpoints here shows that it indeed reaches this point and all variables exist. But the label simply doesn't update. Calling the same `setText` method in `willActivate`, for example, updates it correctly. It's only when returning from this delegate call it doesn't. I have this occurring in a similar place elsewhere in the app too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only update interface elements during initialization and when an interface controller is considered "active." A `WKInterfaceController` is active between the `willActivate` and `didDeactivate` calls. Specifically, you can update the interface within `willActivate`, but you cannot update during `didDeactivate`.

When you call your delegate, it will have to remember to make the requested update during its `willActivate` call. That will happen as soon as the modal is dismissed.

You can learn more about this in my [WatchKit Controller Life Cycle](http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/118262770484/watchkit-controller-life-cycle) post.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! For those wondering, this meant that in the parent controller who implements the delegate method I set the updated property, but moved the `setText` method to within the `willActivate` method.